# Tree view plus minus icon larger

Tags: c#, treeview, icons

How do i make the plus minus icons bigger in the tree view in C# .net with out making visual styles disable.

Comment: Please specify which technology you are using. WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you have any control about it. The only thing you can do is override the DrawNode event and paint the nodes yourself.

First you need to change the DrawMode to OwnerDrawAll. Take a look at the relevant msdn page, it contains surprisingly much detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late... but just ran into this, and discovered (by accident) that there is an (indirect) way to control the size of the plus/minus signs on the TreeView (in WinForms).

You basically have to add an image list, and the TreeView plus/minus signs will change with the size of the images.  To see this in the designer, do the following:

1. Create a TreeView on a form, and and some dummy nodes to it (making sure to have children nodes)
2. Create an image list and give it to the tree view (set it into the ImageList property)
3. Set the ImageSize of the image list to 16,16 and the Indent of the tree view to 3 + the size of the image (19), and the ItemHeight of the tree view to the size of the image list (16).
4. Go into the ImageList and change the ImageSize property to 24, 24, and change the Indent and ItemHeight properties as in step 3 (to 27 and 24 respectively).  You should now have bigger Plus/Minus signs in the tree view.

I do not believe that you have to have images in the list, though I have not tried it that way.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I tried this with 40x40 imagelist and not see any change of plus/minus icon size. Was using .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Bigger than the default 10px or so? I think follow the answer above, but because I came across this while trying to determine how to restore the original size:

Turns out you have some control if you set the indent property - anything less than 10 px starts to shrink the +/- icons. I had a treeview that was being set with an indent of 5, and I found that by restoring it to 15 (or even 10) restored the icon size.

I hope that helps someone else looking for a solution in that area.